# Is it possible to connect google cloud storage with QGIS

Tags: google-cloud-storage, qgis

I am trying to connect google cloud storage with QGIS.

Currently have a few big raster layers stored in google cloud buckets. I've tried the following:

gs://my-bucket/

gs://my-bucket/layer.tif

This is not working and can't find much information about how to authenticate. Anyone has worked this out?

[Trying this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTmYh.png)